# How to write a counter object to a text file?

Tags: python, nlp

There is a large text file(corpus), I need to calculate the count of each word in the file and write the output to another file as below:

a 56
b 23
c 45

Note: I am using Counter to calculate the count of each word in the input file

Comment: You can't directly write a counter object to a text file. Try using pickle if you want to have the counter object freezed in its state. But the best suggestion is to go for sklearn.CountVectorizer if you are using the count for nlp tasks.

Comment: Use `json`, it is totally natural for this use case. A `Counter` *is a* `dict`, and `dict` objects are already serializable with `json`. Don't roll your own text-based format.

Comment: Please show us some code!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have a text file and you need to count the words in it right?

```
word_list = {}
with open('words.txt', 'r') as f:
    words = tuple(f.read().split())
    print(words)
    for word in words:
        if word in word_list: word_list[word] += 1
        else: word_list[word] = 1
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for k, v in word_list.items(): f.write(f'{k} {v}\n')

# written in python 3
```